# how to import excel file from sheet no and from and to raw no given by user in data adaptar

Tags: c#, excel

```
  using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string sheetNo ="Sheet" +txtImportExcelSheetNo.Text+"$";
                    sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        string toRow = txtImportExcelToRw.Text;
                        string fromRow = txtImportExcelfromRw.Text;
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            //Read Data from the First Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();

                        //Populate DataGridView.

                    }
```

where sheetno, toRow and fromRow is given by user to load a excel sheet.and want to import excel file
and i want to load excel sheet in datatable.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datatable.clone()

please review below code:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName  + "]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();

  DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
                            dtnew=dt.Clone();
                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                           for (int i = fromrow; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    DataRow dtRow = dt.Rows[i];
                                    dtnew.ImportRow(dtRow);
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is super-awsome tool called (NuGet) [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). You can use it to manipulate Excel files easily.

I can't provide you full answer, because request `please give me a solution` is to broad. YOu must try on your own first.

Comment: i want to import excel file with sheet no, and from row no and to row number which is given by user